# Python interaction between __setattr__ and self.__dict__

Tags: python

If I make a class instance like this

```
class MyClass(object):
    pass
x = MyClass()
```

I can then set attributes on x as follows:

`x.myAttr = 1` or `x.__setattr__('myAttr', 1)`

However, if I make a dict

```
d = {}
```

I cannot set attributes on it. For example, if I do this

```
d.__setattr__('myAttr', 1)
```

I get the error " 'dict' object has no attribute 'myAttr' " The same thing happens if I try

```
d.myAttr = 1
```

I have noticed that in the case of x.myAttr = 1 what actually happens is that

```
x.__dict__
```

gets updated with a new key, so it must be that

```
d.__setattr__
```

doesn't work because d doesn't have

```
d.__dict__
```

simply because d *is* a dict. I would appreciate it very much if someone could thoroughly explain what's going on here.

Do all python objects have `.__dict__`?

Why does my attempt at calling `d.__setattr__` result in an error saying that the attribute doesn't exist?

Is there a specific heirarchy of built-in types that I should know about? A simple reference would be much appreciated.

python 2.6.4

Windows XP Pro x64 SP2

Answer (score 5):

A `dict` instance doesn't have a `__dict__` attribute, so you can't assign attributes on it. Most of Python's built-in classes (which are written in C and define attributes differently) don't. If you subclass `dict`, the subclass will have a `__dict__` attribute and you can then add attributes to instances of the subclass.

Comment: I see. So is it in some sense correct to imagine that self.__setattr__ works as self.__setattr__(name, value) <=> self.__dict__.__setitem__(name, value)?

Comment: @MartinisGroup No, it does not have do. It can (and is, e.g. in some libraries) be overriden to do something different. Also, while you didn't explicitly say so, you seem to think that `__setattr__` is the key to attribute assignment. It isn't, descriptors (e.g. properties) also have a role and built-in objects are weird in any case.

Comment: Yeah, "built-in objects are weird" cuts to the root of things.

Answer (score 3):

copy-paste from docs.python.org:

> A special attribute of every module is __dict__. This is the dictionary
>   containing the  module’s symbol table. Modifying this dictionary will
>   actually change the module’s symbol table, but direct assignment to the
>   __dict__ attribute is not possible (you can write m.__ dict__['a'] = 1,
>   which defines m.a to be 1, but you can’t write  m.__dict__ = {}).
>   Modifying __dict__ directly is not recommended.

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

The method

Both lines do the same:

```
x.__setattr__('a', b)
x.a = b
```

Like __ add__ is:

```
x.__add__(b)
x + b
```

However, you can redefine a dict.__ setattr__ function to whatever you want

edit for 3rd comment:

```
class x(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __setattr__(self, a, b):
        print "nope, i will not set the attribute %s = %s" % (a,b)

c = x()
c.a = 4
print c.__dict__
```

will print "nope, i will not set the attribute a = 4
and `c.__dict__` won't have the attribute 'a'

Comment: I understand that foo.__setattr__('a', b) does the same thing as foo.a = b. What I don't understand is why I can't do either of these on a dict.

Comment: because dict object has `__setattr__` defined like he wants to

Comment: Ok, your edit for 3rd comment implies that self.__setattr__(name, val) invokes something like self.__dict__.__setitem__(name, val). Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Explanation of exception:

```
>>> class C(object):
...     __slots__ = ('a', 'b')
... 
>>> c = C()
>>> c.a = 1
>>> c.t = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 't'
```

slots described [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots)

Comment: Does your post imply that __slots__ is used by built in types in a way that disallows doing __setattr__ on dict instances? Please explain how your post answers my original questions ^^

Comment: @Martinis Group, `dict` type are implemented in code of interpreter, and can not be changed - only subclassed. __slots__ can be used in user defined classes

Answer (score 0):

`self.__dict__` is a `dict`. 
Suppose, `dict` also had a `__dict__`, its a recursive definition and things wont work :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you do `x.myAttr = 1`, you are really doing `x.__dict__['myAttr'] = 1`. If you did `x.__dict__.myAttr` you would get the same error as with `d.myAttr`. The .`attribute` assignment is defined for classes but not dicts - dict assignment is via `d['attribute']` instead.